Blazor server SignalR is not updating view after receiving message from NotificationHub with .NET 8
Recently we have updated our Blazor server app from .NET 6 to .NET 8. After this upgrade, we noticed that SignalR is not updating view when some messages are received through RebusQueue.
I am using a sample Blazor web application to troubleshoot the issue.
In App.razor I have:
<HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
<Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />

We have the following Rebus configuration in the startup:
builder.Services.AddRebus(configure => configure
    .Transport(x => x.UseSqlServer(transportOptions, queueName))
    .Options(o => o.EnableMulticastRequestReply())
    .Routing(r => r.TypeBased()
        .MapSignalRCommands<NotificationsHub>(queueName))
    .Subscriptions(s =>
        s.StoreInSqlServer("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=neocenter;Encrypt=false;User Id=sa;Password=testrebus",
        "Subscriptions", false)));

// ..............
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapHub<NotificationsHub>("/chatapi"); });

Then in counter.razor, up on incrementing the counter, I am calling
hubContext?.Clients?.All?.SendAsync("sendMessage", "Counter incremented" + currentCount);

I created a NotificationListener where in onInitializeAsync I have
hubConnection = HubConnectionProvider.GetHubConnection(uri);

hubConnection.On<string>("sendMessage", async (message) =>
    {
        await OnMessageReceivedCallback.InvokeAsync(message);
        StateHasChanged();
    });

if (hubConnection is {State: HubConnectionState.Disconnected})
    try
    {
        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.LogError(e, "StartAsync failed");
    }

And a parameter
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<string> OnMessageReceivedCallback { get; set; }

In Weather.razor, I want to receive this message, so I have
<NotificationListener OnMessageReceivedCallback="@HandleNotification"></NotificationListener>

private async Task HandleNotification(string message)
{
    var list = forecasts.ToList();

    int.TryParse(message.Substring(message.Length - 1), out counter);

    list.Add(new WeatherForecast() { Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now), Summary = message, TemperatureC = counter });
    forecasts = list.ToArray();

    StateHasChanged();
}

The problem I am facing is I am seeing that the message is getting received in Weather.razor and the forecasts list is getting updated, but the view is not reflecting this change.

You are calling StateHasChanged from an event. maybe you just need to invoke the UI thread : InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);

Debug breakpoints can be misleading about component state.  Add some Console.WriteLines to your code to make sure that things are happening in the sequence you believe including @{ Console.WriteLine("Log => Index Rendered"); } in the razor markup to log the actual renders.

@Bisjob - you should get an exception if you try to run UI code outside the UI thread.

@'MrC aka Shaun Curtis' yeah I agree, but as it is server rendered I was not sure if the exception could be handled
